# How to create a regex that matches numbers that have 3 or less than 3 digits?

Tags: regex

I want to delete any numbers that have 3 or less than 3 digits. Can someone please help me with a regex that does this?

Currently, my code removes all the numbers it finds.

```
     # Cleans Numbers
     def cleanNumbers(stringToClean):
       stringToClean = re.sub(r'[0-9]*', r'', stringToClean)

       print 'String after cleaning : %s' %stringToClean

       return stringToClean
```

Numbers will be surrounded by space. Example string I pass into the function :

connection breaks on Win8 client after a while. [persistence] 123 1 22 333 4444 554665 645fdgf45 ds3434 457870978934787843 345342kl

I call the above function as follows :

```
# Main function, calls other functions          
def main():

   # Parsing the input query
   searchQuery = open('input.txt', 'r').read()
   print 'Input query : %s' %searchQuery

   # Cleaning the input query
   string = CleanUpText.cleanNumbers(searchQuery)
```

Comment: Could you make up your mind if you want to "remove numbers that have less than 3 digits" or "3 or less than 3 digits"?

Comment: Will the numbers be surrounded by spaces, or other (non-numeric) characters, or what? Do you have some sample strings?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it doesn't matter.  If the numbers were surrounded by numbers (?!) they'd be...bigger numbers.  And by definition they'd then be longer than three digits and would not be removed.

Comment: I have corrected the question, '3 or less than 3' and added an example string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\b[0-9]{1,3}\b` finds blocks of digits that have up to three digits.

Comment: op said many things.. *How to create a regex that matches numbers that have 3 or less than 3 digits?*

Comment: This worked for me. stringToClean = re.sub(r'\b[0-9]{1,3}\b', r'', stringToClean) Removed -> 123 1 22 333 from the input string. Thanks! P.S.: What is op?

Comment: i believe it is *original poster*

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r'[0-9]{,3}',r'',stringToClean)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have corrected the question, '3 or less than 3'

Given that, it should be as simple as: `\b\d{1,3}\b`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regex like this

```
r'\b[0-9]{1,2}\b'
```

Edit: Sorry wrote my answer to fast without really thinking. You have to use boundries so you don't capture 3456 for example

Comment: wouldn't this catch '1234' ?